# JSON validation using github workflow

Tags: github, gitlab-ci, github-actions

I am trying to validation JSONs using Github workflow. But the problem here is that I have multiple JSON files that I need to validate. I tried looking up for a way to validate all of them everywhere but there is none that I could find.

My work flow code is here.

```
name: Validate JSONs

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  verify-json-validation:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Validate JSON
        uses: docker://orrosenblatt/validate-json-action:latest
        env:
          INPUT_SCHEMA: /.github/workflows/schema.json
          INPUT_JSONS: /*.json
```

I am unable to understand how I can add the `INPUT_JSONS` path dynamically so that it could validate all jsons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That usecase is part of pending tickets:

- [`OrRosenblatt/validate-json-action` issue 22](https://github.com/OrRosenblatt/validate-json-action/issues/22): [Feature] Detect JSON Files
- [`OrRosenblatt/validate-json-action` PR 23](https://github.com/OrRosenblatt/validate-json-action/pull/23): Added Glob Functionality

By making your own fork of that action, using PR 23 mentioned above, you would have support for `*.json`.